# How to retrieve data from two tables using a foreach Using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.7

So I need to get data from multiple tables and I'm having trouble doing so.

I have two model classes :

- Thesis_Supervisor : has a supervisor id and a thesis id
- Thesis : has every information about the thesis (id, subject, author...)

What I want to do is, considering a supervisor id, I want to know which thesis he supervises and all the infos about the thesis.

Here's my code :

in my Thesis Supervisor Controller I have this function :

```
public function listOfThesisBySupervisor($id=null){
        $result = $this->ThesisSupervisor->find('all', [
            'conditions' => ['supervisor_id' => $id],
        ]);
        $resultset=array();
        foreach($result as $row){
            $this->loadModel('Theses');
            $query = $this->Theses->find('all');
            array_push($resultset,$query->where(['id' => $row->these_id])->toArray());
        }
        $this->set('Thesis', $resultset);
        }
    }
```

this function is :

- getting all the thesis linked to a given supervisor
- uses a foreach to go through the different thesis
- stores the thesis infos in the variable *resultset*
- returns it to the view

here's the code in the view :

```
<div class="thesis index large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <h3><?= __('Thesis') ?></h3>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('sujet') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('type') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('date_debut') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('date_fin') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('signature') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('auteur_id') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($Theses as $thesis): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($thesis->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($thesis->subject) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($thesis->type) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($thesis->beginning) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($thesis->ending) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($thesis->sign) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So with this code, I do find a correct number of results, but they are not recognised in the view, I get this type of error for each field of the thesis :

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

I tried many different syntaxes to do this (I tried removing the ->toArray in the foreach to have an object but I have an undefined property error for each field of the thesis), but none of them worked. I think the problem is adding the results of each foreach loop to the resultset variable, but I don't see how to fix it...

EDIT : as ndm suggested in his comment I looked more into the associations (as my model classes are linked together with associations) and here my final code :

```
$result = $this->ThesisSupervisor->find('all', [
                'conditions' => ['supervisor_id' => $id],
                'contain' => ['Thesis']
            ]);
            $resultset=array();
            foreach ($result as $row){
                $resultset[]=$row["thesis"];
            }
            $this->set('Theses', $resultset);
```

it is much simpler than my original code and works perfectly.

Comment: You should read about [**associations**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html), the ORM can do that for you in a way more efficient manner.

Comment: thank you for your help. I found the solution, it is in fact way more efficient and simpler